# QLIKVIEW - Scatter chart - popup - right to left

Tags: qlikview

Is there any way to set the text in the pop-up of the scatter chart to be from right to left?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As with many things in Qlik, there is no way to accomplish this directly through the properties dialog. However, you can manually mimic this by substringing a string of whitespace in your expression names. The below function will pad the left side of your label with whitespace.

Expression Label Dialog:

```
=Mid('                              ',1,len('                              ') - len('Exp Label')) & 'Exp Label'
```

The length of the whitespace string is however wide you would want you pop-up window to be.

You may want to store your whitespace string in a variable to make the label look less ugly.

'Exp Label' is whatever you want your expression label to be named. *It shouldn't be longer than your whitespace string.

Comment: Hi. Tnx. It didnt work.  I inserted this code into the expression's label.

Comment: What text did you substitute in for 'Exp Label'?

Comment: The expression field. (with out the apostrophe..)

Comment: Let's say your expression is called `Total Sales`, your label will be: `=Mid('                              ',1,len('                              ') - len('Total Sales')) & 'Total Sales'`. You don't substitute the expression itself, rather the string literal of the expression name.